# using untill loop to monitor multiple processes

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I've found that until loop is a great way to monitor and restart a process if it dies for whatever reason

```
until myserver; do
    echo "Server 'myserver' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

is there any way to get something like

```
until myserver; myserver2 , myserver3 ; do
    echo "Server 'myserver1' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    echo "Server 'myserver2' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    echo "Server 'myserver3' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

Sorry for being a noob...

Comment: Please explain, just in simple plain English, what you want to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run three separate loops in parallel.

```
until myserver; do
  echo "...." >&2
  sleep 1
done &

until myserver2; do
  echo "...." >&2
  sleep 1
done &

until myserver3; do
  echo "...." >&2
  sleep 1
done & 

wait
```

Once all the loops have been started in the background, use `wait` to wait for each loop to complete successfully.